# Simulate a click on tabpanel in ExtJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, testing, extjs

Let me begin by saying that this problem is specific to TabPanel in ExtJS library.
I can successfuly simulate clicks on other ExtJS components using jQuery("#id").click() function.

But I cannot simulate user click on a given tab of TabPanel in ExtJS using jQuery. I see that the dom structure behind tabs looks like this:

```
<ul class="x-tab-strip x-tab-strip-top" id="ext-gen15">
  <li id="ext-comp-1009__ext-comp-1001" class="x-tab-strip-active">
    <a class="x-tab-strip-close" id="ext-gen18"></a>
    <a href="#" class="x-tab-right" id="ext-gen19">
      <em class="x-tab-left">
        <span class="x-tab-strip-inner">
          <span class="x-tab-strip-text">Submarine</span>
        </span>
      </em>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li id="ext-comp-1009__ext-comp-1003" class="">
    <a class="x-tab-strip-close" id="ext-gen20"></a>
    <a href="#" class="x-tab-right" id="ext-gen21">
      <em class="x-tab-left">
        <span class="x-tab-strip-inner">
          <span class="x-tab-strip-text">SpaceShuttle</span>
        </span>
      </em>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="x-tab-edge" id="ext-gen16">
    <span class="x-tab-strip-text">&#160;</span>
  </li>
  <div class="x-clear" id="ext-gen17"></div>
</ul>
```

I've tried various methods of selecting the first tab using jQuery:

```
jQuery("#ext-comp-1009__ext-comp-1001").click();
jQuery("#ext-gen18").click();
jQuery("#ext-gen19").click();
```

but none of it seem to work.

Comment: You can use Ext.getCmp then call fireEvent() on the component for the click event.

Comment: Yes I can but I want to do this with jQuery. Why doesn't jQuery way work for selecting a tab in TabPanel?

Comment: Why are you doing this with jQuery? Seems since you have Ext that's entirely pointless?

Comment: Just out of pure curiosity. I would like to understand why click on TabPanel simulated via jQuery does not work while click on Button works.

Comment: Ahh I see, that's interesting yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you [take a look at the source](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/source/TabPanel.html#method-Ext.TabPanel-activate) (search for `onStripMouseDown` in particular) you'll see that it's expecting an `Ext.EventObject`. It'll fail straight away because `e.button` isn't 0.

Presumably you could patch it with your own `onStripMouseDown`.